# Alternative to rand() or random() in C++

Tags: c++, random

I want to replace [rand()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) (or random()) with a (cryptographically) **secure** random number generator. It should also be **portable**.

I have already found two alternatives:

1. [RAND_bytes()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/RAND_bytes.html)
2. [getrandom()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html)

However, I don't know how to convert the following simple code into these alternatives:

```
rand() % X     // X is an integer
```

Or do you know better generators?

Comment: I don't think it's specified to be cryptocraphically secure, but reasonably portable. You could  use `std::random_device` - but check that it has entropy first. The only real solution is probably to bring in a non-standard generator.

Comment: The problem with trying to use a truly random source of entropy for the random number generator is that on a PC it does not provide random bits fast enough (unless custom hardware is used) to be practical.  The usual approach is to seed a pesudo-random generator (from the truly random generator) and reseed it at intervals when the true random bit generator has had enough time to generate more random data.

Comment: Do you really need cryptographic random numbers? Even if `rand()` was cryptographically random then `rand() % X` probably wouldn't be. If you really need cryptographic random numbers then use a cryptography library, e.g. openssl or crypto++

Comment: I agree, use a dedicated library and do not implement any transformations yourself (like mapping it to a certain range). Use libraries for this. There are many subtle pitfalls regarding pseudo random numbers.

Comment: You have the [Chacha algorithm](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2020/02/22/chacha-rng-with-fewer-rounds/) which is cryptographically secure; for implementation details, see also [RFC 8439](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8439)